# Passing null to the Overloaded methods

Tags: java, object, null, integer

I am confused with the Output of the following two programs.

When I'm only having two methods with parameters as `String` and `Object` in Program 1 it gives me output as `String`.

But when I add a new method with parameter as `Integer` in Program 2 it won't compile and gives error as
**The method nullTest(Object) is ambiguous for the type testNull**

***Program 1 :***

```
package onkartest;

public class TestNull {
    public static void nullTest(Object b)
    {
        System.out.println("object");
    }       
    
    public static void nullTest(String x)
    {
        System.out.println("String");
    }

    public static void main(String x[])
    {           
        nullTest(null);         
    }
}
```

*Output : String*

***Program 2 :***

```
package onkartest;

public class TestNull {
    public static void nullTest(Object b)
    {
        System.out.println("object");
    }       
    
    public static void nullTest(String x)
    {
        System.out.println("String");
    }
 
    public static void nullTest(Integer i)
    {
        System.out.println("Integer ");
    }
    
    public static void main(String x[])
    {       
        nullTest(null);     
    }
}
```

*Output :*

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> The method nullTest(Object) is ambiguous for the type testNull
>
> at onkartest.testNull.main(testNull.java:26)

And also if I run the program with keeping only `Object` parameter method, it gives me output as `Object`.

Can you explain me the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: @Onkar Nevgi The ambiguity in your program is not because both are child class of the Object but becuase none of the child classes share any parent child relationship.

Comment: @Onkar Nevgi Hope you understand the difference between the two.

Comment: Yes . Understood the logic .

Answer (score 2):

When determining which function to use, Java will try to find the function with the most specific input parameter. So in the first case, the String function was chosen as null can be assigned to a String. Object is a parent of String so the String function will be more specific.

In the second case, both Integer and String inherits from Object, and both of these can be assigned to null. Therefore, both of them are equally specific and Java cannot decide which one of these functions to use.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that in case of method overloading,when a parameter is passed that can be referenced by both child and parent class, *the method with the parameter of type child class will always be called.*

The String is a subclass of Object and therefore its method is called.

In the following example we have class `Parent` that can be considered as `Object` class and `Child` class that can be considered as `String` class.

Now what happens with your program 1, exactly the same thing happens, that is the method with parameter of child class object gets called

```
public class Program 
{
 public static void method(Parent p1)//Consider the Parent as Object 
 {
     System.out.println("parent");   
 }
 public static void method(Child c)//Consider the Child as String
 {
     System.out.println("Child");    
 } 
 public static void main(String []args)
 {
     method(null);
 }     
}
class Parent//consider Parent as Object
{

}
class Child extends Parent//consider Child as String
{

}
```

But suppose now you add the following class `Child2` that can be considered as your `Integer` class. `Child2` is a subclass of `Parent`, just like `Integer` is a subclass of `Object`

```
class Child2 extends Parent
{

}
```

and add the following method

```
public static void method(Child2 c)//Consider the Child2 as Integer 
 {
     System.out.println("Child");    
 }
```

Now what happens is exactly what happend in your program 2. The reason is that the compiler is not able to decide which is the right one because of the ambiguity because both are child class of the same same parent class and **most importantly none of them(Either Child2 or Child) is a parent of the other**.

**If we had a case where we have either of the 2 classes a subclass of the other and both inherit Parent class**, then there would be no ambiguity and the method with child class will be called.

Answer (score 1):

When try to pass the arguments to a method it first try a exact same type. if not then try to have immediate super type. in first program Object is super than string so it match with String. But in second program Object class have two children in same level so java compiler is not able to find which one to be mapped the null value.

Comment: I think you meant, "In first program Object is super than string, so it will match with String"